# Gatsby new fails to install the sharp package and breaks

Tags: npm, npm-install, gatsby, sharp

I can't initiate a gatsby starter project. The `new` command process breaks down during initialization, and results in an error and non-compilable project.

Here's the command:

```
> gatsby new gatsby-test
```

The follwing process starts, failing when during `npm install` when the sharp package is attempting to install.

```
info Creating new site from git:
Cloning into 'gatsby-test'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 10, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (10/10), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Total 2309 (delta 4), reused 10 (delta 4), pack-reused 2299
Receiving objects: 100% (2309/2309), 12.62 MiB | 7.98 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1487/1487), done.
success Created starter directory layout
info Installing packages...

> sharp@0.23.2 install /home/developer/projects/gatsby-test/node_modules/sharp
> (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)

info sharp Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.8.1/libvips-8.8.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
fs.js:114
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, copyfile '/tmp/1890-libvips-8.8.1-linux-x64.tar.gz' -> '/home/developer/.npm/_libvips/libvips-8.8.1-linux-x64.tar.gz'
    at Object.copyFileSync (fs.js:1728:3)
    at WriteStream.<anonymous> (/home/developer/projects/gatsby-test/node_modules/sharp/install/libvips.js:104:16)
    at WriteStream.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at lazyFs.close (internal/fs/streams.js:207:14)
    at FSReqWrap.args [as oncomplete] (fs.js:140:20)
make: Entering directory '/home/developer/projects/gatsby-test/node_modules/sharp/build'
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/libvips-cpp.stamp
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o
In file included from ../src/common.cc:25:0:
/usr/include/vips/vips8:35:10: fatal error: glib-object.h: No such file or directory
 #include <glib-object.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
sharp.target.mk:129: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/developer/projects/gatsby-test/node_modules/sharp/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-70-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/developer/projects/gatsby-test/node_modules/sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v10.17.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sharp@0.23.2 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.23.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/developer/.npm/_logs/2019-11-18T16_45_16_026Z-debug.log

 ERROR 

Command failed with exit code 1: npm install



  Error: Command failed with exit code 1: npm install

  - error.js:56 makeError
    [lib]/[gatsby-cli]/[execa]/lib/error.js:56:11

  - index.js:114 handlePromise
    [lib]/[gatsby-cli]/[execa]/index.js:114:26

  - next_tick.js:68 process._tickCallback
    internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7
```

Any idea what's going on here? I saw there were some problems with `sharp` in the past but that is supposed to be a closed and fixed issue now. What am I missing here?

Comment: The gatsby project maintainers recommend `yarn` for building the project. `npm` regularly causes these unexplainable build bugs. I know you should have the choice of package manager. From my experience, since I've used yarn I did not encounter these bugs anymore.

Comment: @EliteRaceElephant But all the documentation tutorials and examples are done with npm, is the yarn and official recommendation?

Comment: I also solved this by switching from npm to yarn.

Answer (score 5):

You can fix this by running the below in your terminal...

```
rm -rf /Users/{username}/.npm/_libvips

brew install vips 

rm -rf node_modules

npm install
```

Answer (score 3):

The following line:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, copyfile '/tmp/1890-libvips-8.8.1-linux-x64.tar.gz' -> '/home/developer/.npm/_libvips/libvips-8.8.1-linux-x64.tar.gz'
```

suggests you have a permissions error moving  tmp file to your users local .npm directory. Hard to tell why this is without knowing more context about which user ran the command, etc.

---

The following line:

```
fatal error: glib-object.h: No such file or directory
```

suggests you don't have `sharp` or `vips` correctly installed.

```
npm install sharp
```

For Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libvips-tools
```

For mac:

```
brew update vips
```

For archlinux/manjaro:

```
sudo pacman -S libvips
```

Comment: I have it installed, running `sudo apt-get install -y libvips-tools` confirms it. The problem persists.
`

Comment: How about `sharp`? Test with `npm view sharp version`

Comment: But should `sharp` be globally installed? `gatsby new <dir>` expects the directory to not exist. How can i install any npm module to it?

Comment: Also, try `sudo gatsby new gatsby-test`, and see what happens. If this runs without errors, it looks to be a permissions error, and if that is the case I'd hazard a guess it's because of installing gatsby using `sudo` (e.g., `sudo npm i -g gatsby`)

Comment: `npm view sharp version` outputs: `0.23..3`

Comment: @aviya.developer Then you're probably okay re `sharp` dependency. I'd personally check next if it could be permissions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203235/discussion-between-nick-bull-and-aviya-developer).

Comment: I installed gatsby with `sudo` and also tried running the command with `sudo`, the output of the question is the result of `sudo gatsby new <dir>`

Comment: Maybe global npm permissions error. Try the following: `mkdir ~/.npm-global; npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global`. Then add the following line to `~/.profile`: `export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`. Now run `. ~/.profile`, and try to re-install gatsby globally (`npm i -g gatsby`)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I solved it by downloading the package manually and pasting in

1. download the libvips from https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.8.1/libvips-8.8.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
2. copy the lib into .npm folder

> sudo cp libvips-8.8.1-linux-x64.tar.gz /home/[YOURNAME]/.npm/_libvips/

3. remove your broken gatsby-test folder
4. run

> gatsby new gatsby-test

again

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, I ran:

- `rm -rf node_modules`
- `yarn cache clean`
- `yarn add --dev yarn-upgrade-all`
- `npx yarn-upgrade-all`

Then, I re-installed all necessary packages removed from package.json when I ran the command to upgrade all packages.
Afterwards, I ran `gatsby build` and `gatsby develop`

Answer (score 0):

Try the sudo command. If you're happy with applying root perms to the install.

Comment: Please use comments for this type of suggestions