# Unable to run Gatsby project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

When I run Gatsby v2.19.19 I get the following error

`Gatsby requires Node.js 14.15.0 or higher (you have v12.13.0)`

The problem is if that I switch to anything higher than 14.15.0 some of my dependecies won't install no matter what I do. For instance, `gatsby-plugin-favicon` `gatsby-transformer-sharp` `gatsby-plugin-sharp` that all depend on the package called `sharp`

I also can't install the dependecies using node v12 and then switch to v14 and run the project cause of the same package (the docs explicitly state that it has to be installed and run on the same version of node)

Also, in Gatsby v2 -> v3 migration guide it says that minimal required node version for v3 is 12.13.0. Given that I work with v2 it should even be lower than that, therefore I do not understand the error that says that I have to have 14.15.0 or above.

Here is my `package.json` file

```
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "build:develop": "OSS_ENV=staging gatsby build",
    "build": "OSS_ENV=production gatsby build",
    "serve": "gatsby serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.13.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "email-validator": "^2.0.4",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager": "^2.1.25",
    "gatsby-plugin-robots-txt": "^1.5.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^2.2.27",
    "pngquant-bin": "^6.0.0",
    "superagent": "^6.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "antd": "^3.26.11",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "gatsby": "^2.19.18",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.2.41",
    "gatsby-plugin-antd-v2": "^1.0.3",
    "gatsby-plugin-favicon": "^3.1.6",
    "gatsby-plugin-less": "^4.7.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.1.22",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^3.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.4.5",
    "gatsby-plugin-typescript": "^2.1.27",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.1.48",
    "gatsby-source-ghost": "^4.2.2",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.3.14",
    "less": "^4.1.1",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0"
  }
```

The error I get while installing the packages I mentioned above on node v14.15.0 or above

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sharp@0.23.4 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.23.4 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: What do you mean by “won’t install”? Do they show an error?

Comment: When you upgrade the Node version to 14, have you removed the `package-lock.json` and the `node_modules`?

Comment: @FerranBuireu yes I have

Comment: @evolutionxbox I have updated my question with the error

Comment: It sounds like `sharp` needs to be updated?

Comment: I did that too. 
Is there a way to ignore the warning about the node version? Obviously it should work with node v12 according to their own doc

Comment: Not likely. A minimum version exists, because the code will likely not work on older versions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried playing with `libvips` dependency?

According to some [GitHub threads](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/20320#issuecomment-573040166), the issue seems that `libvips` is a dependency for `sharp` which `gatsby-plugin-sharp` uses (present in your `package.json`). Just to confirm that this plugin is the cause of your issue, try removing it and reinstalling the modules again.

To bypass this issue you can try [installing `libvips`](https://github.com/libvips/libvips/#install) manually:

```
rm -rf /Users/{username}/.npm/_libvips
brew install vips 
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Of course, this assumes a MacOS system.

Other threads suggest switching from npm to yarn.

Related issues:

- [Gatsby new fails to install the sharp package and breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58919394/gatsby-new-fails-to-install-the-sharp-package-and-breaks)